# How to calculate different alphabet number between two strings in bash?

Tags: bash

```
a="ABCDEFG"  
b="ABCDXYG"
```

How can I calculate different alphabet number between these two strings in bash?
In this case the answer is 2 (`E != X` and `F != Y`).

Comment: Would `a=AB; b=BA` also be considered having differences, or should they be considered the same?

Comment: @user1934428 They are considered as different ones.

Comment: Do you really have to do this in Posix shell? It is possible to write it, but very cumbersome. If you could use bash or zsh, or some more general programming language (Ruby, Perl, ... even awk would be better suitable), it would be much easier.

Comment: @user1934428 `bash` is what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want the number of different letters in the same position in both strings.

So:

1. Insert a newline each character in both strings (so we can parse them in bash)
2. Put first string (with newlines) in one column, the second one in another
3. Print only lines which have different columns
4. Count the lines.

```
paste <(<<<"$a" sed 's/./&\n/g') <(<<<"$b" sed 's/./&\n/g') |
awk '$1 != $2' |
wc -l
```

And just for fun a pure bash solution:

```
declare -i cnt
cnt=0
while 
    IFS= read -r -n1 -u3 c1 &&
    IFS= read -r -n1 -u4 c2
do
    if [ "$c1" != "$c2" ]; then
        cnt=cnt+1
    fi
done 3<<<"$a" 4<<<"$b"
echo "$cnt"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code, with no subprocesses and no I/O:

```
#! /bin/bash

a=ABCDEFG
b=ABCDXYG

declare -i diffcount=0
(( ${#a} < ${#b} )) && maxlen=${#b} || maxlen=${#a}
for ((i=0; i<maxlen; i++)) ; do
    [[ ${a:i:1} != "${b:i:1}" ]] && diffcount+=1
done

echo $diffcount
```

`maxlen` is the maximum of the lengths of the strings.  If one of the strings is longer than the other then each character past the length of the short string in the long string is counted as a difference.  The code will need to be modified if you want a different behaviour.